# Submitting Angular form returns unavailable or undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, forms

I have written a registration page component in Angular. I have followed what few tutorials there are and I have stumbled upon a very frustrating bug. Pressing the submit button on the form will simply cause the console to print out "undefined" when trying to access the NgForm's value. Accessing the "valid" field of the NgForm will return true or false, as expected.

the page:

```
<app-players></app-players>
<div class="container" style="text-align:center">
<h3>Register a new account!</h3>
    <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">
        <label>Username:</label> <input type="text" id="username"
            required #username="ngModel"
            name="username" ngModel><br>
        <label>Password:</label> <input type="password" id="password"
            required #password="ngModel"
            name="password" ngModel><br>
        <label>Email:</label> <input type="text" id="email"
            required #email="ngModel"
            name="email" ngModel><br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!newPlayerEntry.form.valid">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div id = "result">

</div>
```

The component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { NewPlayer } from './new-player';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-players-register',
  templateUrl: './players-register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./players-register.component.css']
})
export class PlayersRegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit(f: NgForm) { 
    console.log(f.value);
  }

}
```

Comment: Remove ```[disabled]="!newPlayerEntry.form.valid"```.. What does ```!newPlayerEntry``` doing here ?? It was nowhere declared.. Instead use ```[disabled]="!f.valid"```.. Working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i7epka

Comment: Have a play with my library Easy Angular, it take a lot of the pain out of forms. https://github.com/adriandavidbrand/ngx-ez Demo at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pytks5

Answer (score 0):

You need remove `[disabled]="!newPlayerEntry.form.valid"` and change to `[disabled]="!f.valid"`

This is working version

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mgmmsq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html